# MySQL: Optimizing COUNT(*) and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a simple MyISAM table resembling the following (trimmed for readability -- in reality, there are more columns, all of which are constant width and some of which are nullable):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `event` (`event`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
);
```

Presently the table contains only about 6,000,000 rows (of which currently about 160,000 match the query below), but this is expected to increase. Given a particular event ID and grouped by source, I want to know how many events with that ID were logged during a particular interval of time. The answer to the query might be something along the lines of "Today, event X happened 120 times for source A, 105 times for source B, and 900 times for source C."

The query I concocted does perform this task, but it performs monstrously badly, taking well over a minute to execute when the timespan is set to "all time" and in excess of 30 seconds for as little as a week back:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM history
WHERE event=2000 AND time >= 0 AND time < 1310563644
GROUP BY source
ORDER BY count DESC
```

This is not for real-time use, so even if the query takes a second or two that would be fine, but several minutes is not. Explaining the query gives the following, which troubles me for obvious reasons:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE          history ref     event,time      event   4           const   160399  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I've experimented with various multi-column indexes (such as (event, time)), but with no improvement. This seems like such a common use case that I can't imagine there not being a reasonable solution, but my Googling all boil down to versions of the query I already have, with no particular suggestions on how to avoid the temporary (and even then, why performance is so abysmal).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You say you have tried multi-column indexes. Have you also tried single-column indexes, one per column?

**UPDATE**: Also, the `COUNT(*)` operation over a `GROUP BY` clause is probably a lot faster, if the grouped column also has an index on it... Of course, this depends on the number of `NULL` values that are actually in that column, which are not indexed.

For `event`, MySQL can execute a `UNIQUE SCAN`, which is quite fast, whereas for `time`, a `RANGE SCAN` will be applied, which is not so fast... If you separate indexes, I'd expect better performance than with multi-column ones.

Also, maybe you could gain something by partitioning your table by some expected values / value ranges:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html

Comment: As you can see from the schema at the top, both event and time are each separately indexed, in addition to the multi-column indexes I tried.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that. I wasn't so familiar with that syntax of specifying `INDEX` using the `KEY` keyword... How about adding an `INDEX` to `source` ?

Comment: Blame phpmyadmin's Export function -- I wasn't used to it either. :) Additionally indexing on source provides no additional benefit in my tests.

Comment: Can you add the INDEX to `source` **AND** make it `NOT NULL` ?

Comment: I'd rather try to avoid tampering with the column definitions if I can avoid it -- if all else fails, I'll give it a try.

Comment: I know. I'd be curious how this could be resolved in MySQL. But usually, `NULL` and `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` is a bad combination resulting in `FULL TABLE SCANS`, because the values are never included in any index. I don't know if MySQL maybe has functional indexes, though?

Answer (score 0):

I offer you to try this multi-column index:

```
ALTER TABLE `history` ADD INDEX `history_index` (`event` ASC, `time` ASC, `source` ASC);
```

Then if it doesn't help, try to force index on this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM history USE INDEX (history_index)
WHERE event=2000 AND time >= 0 AND time < 1310563644
GROUP BY source
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: That particular index is among those I tried when I was toying with multi-column indexes. Forcing the use of the index doesn't seem to affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the source are known or you want to find the count for specific source, then you can try like this.

select count(source= 'A' or NULL) as A,count(source= 'B' or NULL) as B from history;
and for ordering you can do it in your application code. Also try with indexing event and source together.

This will be definitely faster than the older one.

Comment: There are hundreds of different sources, and I require data for all of them in the same query.

Comment: Can you specify the no. of rows matches the time criteria alone and event criteria alone. I mean select count(*) from history where time >0 and time < 1310563644, select count(*) from history where event = 2000

Comment: Can you add results of 'show variables like '%table%'; ' and show status like '%tmp%'; after executing flush status and your query.